# Updating a v-for component in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a component (`NoteCard`) that renders with `v-for` based on values in an array `notes` as IDs. It renders as expected at load time but when I change the number of days (input field with a shared state) and click the reload button - which in turns calls the `reloadNotes` function - it does not update until I change the value of `days` again (I imagine it calls a next tick or some event that rerenders)

When I look for ways for force an update online I can only find answers for previous versions of Vue or answers that don't work from some reason in Nuxt 3.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <button 
            class="btn"
            v-on:click="refresh"
            >
        Reload {{ days || 5 }} days</button>
        <NoteCard v-for="note in notes" :noteID=note :key="note"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const days = useState("days")
    let notes = new Array()
    await reloadNotes()
    
    async function reloadNotes(event) {
        console.log(`reloading ${days.value} days`)
        let response = await useFetch(`/api/notes?days=${days.value}`)
        notes = response.data
    }
</script>
```

**What can I do to have the component render based on the value in the response immediately after it gets it?**

Comment: Tried making `notes` a `ref` so that it's reactive? Here, it's a regular JS variable. `let notes = ref([])` and injecting the result of `useFetch` inside of it. Check your devtools to see if everything works well there or not too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question:*

Immediately after posting this question sumbled upon something that works. I added a call to `refreshNuxtData` at the end of the reload function. like so:

```js
async function reloadNotes(event) {
    console.log(`reloading ${days.value} days`)
    let response = await useFetch(`/api/notes?days=${days.value}`)
    notes = response.data
    refreshNuxtData()
}
```

---

*modified the code based on kissu's comments*:

**This works even better, and with cleaner code**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <button
            class="btn"
            v-on:click="refresh" >
        Reload {{ days || 5 }} days</button>
        <div v-if="!pending">
            <NoteCard v-for="note in notes" :noteID=note :key="note"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const days = useState("days")
    const { pending, data: notes } =
        await useAsyncData('notes', () => $fetch(`/api/notes?days=${days.value}`))
    const refresh = () => { refreshNuxtData('notes')}
</script>
```

Comment: A bit extreme but works too I suppose: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/refresh-nuxt-data